# GridLayout not showing as I expect

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, grid-layout

Sorry, I'm not doing well with layouts. I'm trying to add a button, next to another button, next to some text fields.  When I say the button is in column 3, on the preview it leaps of the screen to the right...  what am I doing wrong?

[image]

```html
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="8"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/itemListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="3"
            android:layout_row="0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Instructions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="Enter details of item to add to you timer list below. Enter the times in seconds. The finish by refers to if you need an item to finish before the end, again in seconds." />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/itemName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Item to add"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/itemTime"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Time in seconds"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/finishTime"
            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/finishTime"
            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/finishTime" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/finishTime"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Seconds it needs to finish by"
            android:inputType="time" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:onClick="addItem"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Add" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/timerButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:text="Start Timer" />


    </GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below answer, i have added **LinearLayout** and **weightSum** to keep

it like **EditText -> Button -> Button**.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/itemListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Instructions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="start|left"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Enter details of item to add to you timer list below. Enter the times in seconds. The finish by refers to if you need an item to finish before the end, again in seconds." />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.3"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/itemName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Item to add"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/itemTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Time in seconds"
                    android:inputType="time"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/finishTime"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/finishTime"
                    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/finishTime" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/finishTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Seconds it needs to finish by"
                    android:inputType="time" />
            </LinearLayout >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addItem"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:onClick="addItem"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:text="Add" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/timerButton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Start Timer" />
            </LinearLayout >
        </LinearLayout >
    </LinearLayout >
</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: isnt this working for you ? inform me if you are stuck.@AndyCr15

Comment: Thanks.  Using that I've redone it, removing the gridlayout completely.  I still have problems with the lower portion, with the text field and buttons.

I have a horizontal linear layout (weightsum 3) that contains a vertical linear layout weight 1 (which then has the EditText's in) and a horiz Linearlayout which has the buttons in, weight 2, but it still looks to be split in half in the weightsum 3 horix linear layout?

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got there.  I am going to make a new question on what I now have though, if you have time to take a look at that, thanks.
**EDIT** In fact, I'm coping myself I think. Thanks.

Comment: check my updated answer, i think your issue will be solved.@AndyCr15

Comment: Thanks, I've done it.  I have upvoted, but as I'm a noob it says it's recorded but not shown...